# making frame modal

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JFrame` with 2 `JTextField`s in it. now I want to make that frame a modal window, how can i do that please tell.

Answer (score 3):

[Simple Modal Dialog](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ASimpleModalDialog.htm)

From the javadoc of class Dialog

> A dialog can be either modeless (the
>   default) or modal.  A modal   dialog
>   is one which blocks input to all other
>   toplevel windows   in the application,
>   except for any windows created with
>   the dialog   as their owner.

```
public class AboutDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
  public AboutDialog(JFrame parent, String title, String message) {
    super(parent, title, true);
    if (parent != null) {
      Dimension parentSize = parent.getSize(); 
      Point p = parent.getLocation(); 
      setLocation(p.x + parentSize.width / 4, p.y + parentSize.height / 4);
    }
    JPanel messagePane = new JPanel();
    messagePane.add(new JLabel(message));
    getContentPane().add(messagePane);
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("OK"); 
    buttonPane.add(button); 
    button.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    pack(); 
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setVisible(false); 
    dispose(); 
  }
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    AboutDialog dlg = new AboutDialog(new JFrame(), "title", "message");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a JDialog instead of a JFrame.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i wanted to ask that cant i make that frame to open in a modal mode?